# Acrobat 9.2.0 License

Tags: adobe-acrobat

I'm about to format a machine and I am wondering if anyone can tell me how to copy an Adobe Acrobat 9 Standard (9.2.0) license so I can reload the software.  I have several re-install disks that were sent as part of Dell's packaging but have no idea how to tie the disc to the license so I was hoping to just be able to copy a specific file or something and reload using a random Acrobat 9 Standard disc.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I found it here

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Adobe\Adobe Acrobat\9.0\Registration\SERIAL
```

Comment: Don't forget to come back in a day or so to mark your answer as correct. This makes it easier if others with the same problem comes along.